# The cardinality of the function

Tags: analysis, functions

I'm reading a book about cardinality of functions and while I was solving some problems of the book I saw this:

Prove that the cardinality of a general function $f:K \to K$ is $n^n$, where $n$ is the number of elements in $K$.
I think I do understand the logic behind this,for example let's say:

$K=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Now the function $f$ has a cardinality of $5^5$ because the first element ($a$) has $5$ opportunities, the second element ($b$) has also $5$ opportunities,the third element ($c$) has also $5$ opportunities and so on.

Now I'm trying to prove this as the task says,but I don't know how to do it,how to write it in a more mathematical way.

Comment: just curious, the name of the book ?!

Comment: I think you mean "the cardinality of *the set of all* functions" rather than "the cardinality of *a* function".

Comment: @Гарнак Олэговытц                                                            Here is the link:http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/Cardinality.pdf                                                                                                          It is not all the  book as you can notice.It is only the 13 chapter.